# Geom_txt does not display correctly in animation

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, gganimate

Sorry for my English.

I'm creating a feature to display the NBA season moving average. I'm doing an animation, part of which is displaying the current rating. I do this with geom_text. The problem is that instead of displaying a single value, you get a jumble.

Code:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

##Getting data via NBA API.
##Required link
adv_box_team <- "https://stats.nba.com/stats/teamgamelogs?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Advanced&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2018-19&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&VsConference=&VsDivision="

##Adding headers
request_headers <- c(
  "accept-encoding" = "gzip, deflate, sdch",
  "accept-language" = "en-US,en;q=0.8",
  "cache-control" = "no-cache",
  "connection" = "keep-alive",
  "host" = "stats.nba.com",
  "pragma" = "no-cache",
  "upgrade-insecure-requests" = "1",
  "user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9"
)

#Getting a response
request <- GET(adv_box_team, add_headers(request_headers))

#Convert to js.file to list
boxscore_data <- fromJSON(content(request, as = "text"))

#Convert to tibble data and assigning column names
table <- tbl_df(data.frame(boxscore_data$resultSets$rowSet[[1]], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
names(table) <- toupper(boxscore_data$resultSets$headers[[1]])

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
library(ggthemes)
library(gganimate)
library(rlang)
library(data.table)

##Cleaning data
rating <- table %>%
  select(TEAM_ID,
         TEAM_ABBREVIATION,
         TEAM_NAME,
         GAME_ID,
         GAME_DATE,
         MATCHUP,
         WL,
         E_OFF_RATING,
         E_DEF_RATING,
         E_NET_RATING)

rating1 <- rating %>%
rename_at(vars(starts_with("E_")),
          funs(str_c(str_sub(., start = 3, end = 3), 
                       str_sub(., start = 7, end = 7),
                       str_sub(., start = 9, end = 9),
                       str_sub(., start = 12, end = 12))))

rolling_offnet_rating_nba <- function(table, variable, name, col1 = col1, col2 = col2){
  quo_rating <- enquo(variable)
  quo_col1 <- enquo(col1)
  quo_col2 <- enquo(col2)

  test1 <- rating1 %>%
    mutate(GAME_DATE = as.Date(ymd_hms(GAME_DATE))) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ORTG:NRTG), list(~as.numeric))

  team <- test1 %>%
    filter(TEAM_ABBREVIATION == name) %>%
    mutate(RATING = rollmeanr(!! quo_rating, k = 10, fill= NA)) %>%
    na.omit(test1)

   league <- test1 %>%
     group_by(TEAM_NAME) %>%
     summarise(ORTG = mean(ORTG),
               DRTG = mean(DRTG),
               NTRG = mean(NRTG))

  average <- league %>%
    mutate(average = mean(!! quo_rating)) %>%
    select(average) %>%
    unique() %>%
    .$average


  top10 <- league %>%
    arrange(desc(!! quo_rating)) %>%
    select(!! quo_rating) %>%
    slice(10)
  top10 <- top10[[1]]

  bottom10 <- league %>%
    arrange(desc(!! quo_rating)) %>%
    select(!! quo_rating) %>%
    slice(21)
  bottom10 <- bottom10[[1]]

  data <- team %>%
    select(GAME_DATE) %>%
    unique() %>%
    arrange(GAME_DATE)
  data <- data[[1,1]]


  table_color <- data.table(TEAM_ID = c(1610612737, 1610612738, 1610612751, 1610612766, 1610612741, 1610612739, 1610612742,
                                     1610612743, 1610612765, 1610612744, 1610612745, 1610612754, 1610612746, 1610612747,
                                     1610612763, 1610612748, 1610612749, 1610612750, 1610612740, 1610612752, 1610612760,
                                     1610612753, 1610612755, 1610612756, 1610612757, 1610612758, 1610612759, 1610612761,
                                     1610612762, 1610612764),
                         TEAM_NAME = c("Atlanta Hawks",          "Boston Celtics",         "Brooklyn Nets",         
                                       "Charlotte Hornets",      "Chicago Bulls",          "Cleveland Cavaliers",   
                                       "Dallas Mavericks",       "Denver Nuggets",         "Detroit Pistons",       
                                       "Golden State Warriors",  "Houston Rockets",        "Indiana Pacers",        
                                       "LA Clippers",            "Los Angeles Lakers",     "Memphis Grizzlies",     
                                       "Miami Heat",             "Milwaukee Bucks",        "Minnesota Timberwolves",
                                       "New Orleans Pelicans",   "New York Knicks",        "Oklahoma City Thunder", 
                                       "Orlando Magic",          "Philadelphia 76ers",     "Phoenix Suns",          
                                       "Portland Trail Blazers", "Sacramento Kings",       "San Antonio Spurs",     
                                       "Toronto Raptors",        "Utah Jazz",              "Washington Wizards"),
                         TEAM_ABBREVIATION = c("ATL", "BOS", "BKN", "CHA", "CHI", "CLE", "DAL", "DEN", "DET", "GSW", "HOU", "IND", "LAC", "LAL",
                                               "MEM", "MIA", "MIL", "MIN", "NOP", "NYK", "OKC", "ORL", "PHI", "PHX", "POR", "SAC", "SAS", "TOR",
                                               "UTA", "WAS"),
                         col1 = c("#E03A3E", "#007A33", "#000000", "#1D1160", "#CE1141", "#6F263D", "#00538C", "#0E2240",
                                  "#C8102E", "#006BB6", "#CE1141", "#002D62", "#C8102E", "#552583", "#5D76A9", "#98002E",
                                  "#00471B", "#0C2340", "#0C2340", "#006BB6", "#007AC1", "#0077C0", "#006BB6", "#1D1160",
                                  "#E03A3E", "#5A2D81", "#C4CED4", "#CE1141", "#002B5C", "#002B5C"),
                         name_col1 = c("HAWKS RED",           "CELTICS GREEN",       "BLACK",              
                                       "HORNETS PURPLE",      "BULLS RED",           "CAVALIERS WINE",     
                                       "ROYAL BLUE",          "MIDNIGHT BLUE",       "RED",                
                                       "WARRIORS ROYAL BLUE", "RED",                 "PACERS BLUE",        
                                       "RED",                 "LAKERS PURPLE",       "BLUE",               
                                       "RED",                 "GOOD LAND GREEN",     "MIDNIGHT BLUE",      
                                       "PELICANS NAVY",       "KNICKS BLUE",         "THUNDER BLUE",       
                                       "MAGIC BLUE",          "BLUE",                "PURPLE",             
                                       "RED",                 "PURPLE",              "SILVER",             
                                       "RED",                 "NAVY",                "NAVY BLUE"),
                         col2 = c("#C1D32F", "#BA9653", "#FFFFFF", "#00788C", "#000000", "#041E42", "#002B5E", "#FEC524",
                                  "#006BB6", "#FDB927", "#000000", "#FDBB30", "#1D428A", "#FDB927", "#12173F", "#F9A01B",
                                  "#EEE1C6", "#236192", "#C8102E", "#F58426", "#EF3B24", "#C4CED4", "#ED174C", "#E56020",
                                  "#000000", "#63727A", "#000000", "#000000", "#00471B", "#E31837"),
                         name_col2 = c("VOLT GREEN",       "CELTICS GOLD",     "WHITE",            "TEAL",            
                                       "BLACK",            "CAVALIERS NAVY",   "NAVY BLUE",        "SUNSHINE YELLOW", 
                                       "ROYAL",            "GOLDEN YELLOW",    "BLACK",            "YELLOW",          
                                       "BLUE",             "GOLD",             "NAVY",             "YELLOW",          
                                       "CREAM CITY CREAM", "LAKE BLUE",        "PELICANS RED",     "KNICKS ORANGE",   
                                       "SUNSET",           "SILVER",           "RED",              "ORANGE",          
                                       "BLACK",            "GRAY",             "BLACK",            "BLACK",           
                                       "GREEN",            "RED"),
                         col3 = c("#26282A", "#963821", NA,        "#A1A1A4", NA,        "#FFB81C", "#B8C4CA", "#8B2131",
                                  "#BEC0C2", "#26282A", "#C4CED4", "#BEC0C2", "#BEC0C2", "#000000", "#F5B112", "#000000",
                                  "#0077C0", "#9EA2A2", "#85714D", "#BEC0C2", "#002D62", "#000000", "#002B5C", "#000000",
                                   NA,        "#000000", NA,        "#A1A1A4", "#F9A01B", "#C4CED4"),
                         name_col3 = c("HAWKS CHARCOAL",   "CELTICS BROWN",    NA,                 "GRAY",            
                                        NA,                 "CAVALIERS NAVY",  "SILVER",           "FLATIRONS RED",   
                                       "GRAY",             "SLATE",            "SILVER",           "SILVER",          
                                       "SILVER",           "BLACK",            "YELLOW",           "BLACK",           
                                       "GREAT LAKES BLUE", "MOONLIGHT GREY",   "PELICANS GOLD",    "KNICKS SILVER",   
                                       "BLUE",             "BLACK",            "NAVY",             "BLACK",           
                                        NA,                "BLACK",            NA,                 "SILVER",          
                                       "YELLOW",           "SILVER" ),
                         col4 = c( NA,        "#E59E6D", NA,        NA,        NA,        "#000000", "#000000", "#1D428A",
                                  "#002D62", NA,        NA,        NA,        "#000000", NA,        "#707271", NA,       
                                  "#000000", "#78BE20", NA,        "#000000", "#FDBB30", NA,        "#C4CED4", "#63727A",
                                   NA,        NA,        NA,        "#B4975A", NA,        NA   ),
                         name_col4 = c( NA,                "CELTICS BEIGE",   NA,                NA,               
                                        NA,                "CAVALIERS BLACK", "BLACK",           "SKYLINE BLUE",   
                                       "NAVY",            NA,                NA,                NA,               
                                       "BLACK",           NA,                "GRAY",            NA,              
                                       "BLACK",           "AURORA GREEN",    NA,                "KNICKS BLACK",   
                                       "YELLOW",          NA,                "SILVER",          "GRAY",           
                                        NA,                NA,                NA,                "GOLD",           
                                        NA,                NA ),
                         col5 = c(NA,        "#000000", NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,       
                                  NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,       
                                  NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        "#F9AD1B",
                                  NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA   ),
                         name_col5 = c(NA,              "CELTICS BLACK", NA,              NA,              NA,             
                                       NA,              NA,              NA,              NA,              NA,             
                                       NA,              NA,              NA,              NA,              NA,             
                                       NA,              NA,              NA,              NA,              NA,             
                                       NA,              NA,              NA,              "YELLOW",        NA,             
                                       NA,             NA,              NA,              NA,              NA  ),
                         col6 = c(NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,       
                                  NA,       NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,       
                                  NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        "#B95915",
                                  NA,        NA,       NA,        NA,        NA,        NA    ),
                         name_col6 = c(NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,           
                                       NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,           
                                       NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,           
                                       NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,            "DARK ORANGE",
                                       NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,            NA,            NA ),
                         col7 = c(NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,       
                                  NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,       
                                  NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        "#BEC0C2",
                                  NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA,        NA ),
                         name_col7 = c(NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,          
                                       NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,          
                                       NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,          
                                       NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           "LIGHT GRAY",
                                       NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA))



  color1 <- table_color %>%
    filter(TEAM_ABBREVIATION == name) %>%
    select(!! quo_col1)
  color1 <- color1[[1]]

  color2 <- table_color %>%
    filter(TEAM_ABBREVIATION == name) %>%
    select(!! quo_col2)
  color2 <- color2[[1]]

  name1 <- paste0("name_", quo_name(quo_col1))
  name2 <- paste0("name_", quo_name(quo_col2))

  name_color1 <- table_color %>%
    filter(TEAM_ABBREVIATION == name) %>%
    select(name1)
  name_color1 <- name_color1[[1]]

  name_color2 <- table_color %>%
    filter(TEAM_ABBREVIATION == name) %>%
    select(name2)
  name_color2 <- name_color2[[1]]

  max <- team %>%
    filter(RATING == max(RATING)) %>%
    select(RATING)
  max <- max[[1]]

  Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")
  gg <- ggplot(team, aes(GAME_DATE, RATING)) +
     geom_hline(yintercept = c(top10, bottom10), col = c("red", "blue")) +
     annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date(data) + 2, y = top10 - 0.2,
              label = "TOP 10", col = "red") +
     annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date(data) + 2, y = bottom10 + 0.2,
              label = "BOTTOM 10", col = "blue") +
      geom_line(size = 2, col = if_else(team$RATING > average, color1, color2)) +
     theme_tufte() +
     labs(title = paste0(team$TEAM_NAME, " 10-Game Rolling Luck-Adjusted ", quo_name(quo_rating)),
          subtitle = paste0(paste0(name_color1, " - above average ", quo_name(quo_rating)),
                            "\n", paste0(name_color2, " - below average ",quo_name(quo_rating))),
          caption = "Source: BBall Index Data & Tools\nTelegram: @NBAatlantic, twitter: @vshufinskiy")
   theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5),
         plot.caption = element_text(size = 10),
         plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 9))
   ggsave(paste0(unique(team$TEAM_NAME), quo_name(quo_rating), ".jpeg"), gg, width = 8, units = "in")

  anim <- gg +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 25),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 15),
          plot.caption = element_text(size = 15),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 18)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = as.Date(data), y = max + 0.5),
              label = paste0(quo_name(quo_rating)," ", round(team$RATING, digits = 1)), size = 6,
              col = if_else(team$RATING > average, color1, color2)) +
    transition_reveal(GAME_DATE) +
    labs(title = paste0(team$TEAM_NAME, " 10-Game Rolling Luck-Adjusted ", quo_name(quo_rating)),
         subtitle = paste0(paste0(name_color1, " - above average ",quo_name(quo_rating)),
                           "\n", paste0(name_color2, " - below average ",quo_name(quo_rating)),
                           "\n", "Date: {frame_along}"),
         caption = paste0("Source: BBall Index Data & Tools\nTelegram: @NBAatlantic, twitter: @vshufinskiy"))

  animate(anim, fps = 5, duration = 5, width = 1280, height = 720,
          renderer = gifski_renderer(paste0(unique(team$TEAM_NAME), quo_name(quo_rating), ".gif")))
}

rolling_offnet_rating_nba(rating1, ORTG, "GSW")
```

Result: https://c.radikal.ru/c40/1907/c8/37e210e3f31b.gif

Comment: Could you provide your variable `data` directly such that people do not need to scrap the info ?. Please, try to provide the minimum code to make the example equally valid, such that anyone can identify the problem faster.

Comment: I realized that geom_text shows the first value and all subsequent ones, but the first one never goes away. The result is an overlay of 2 values: the first and the current.